# XamlParseException when using the XAML Designer

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, designer, xamlparseexception

### Important: Consider every tag in the .xaml codes below closed

I've searched everywhere for the answer but none of the questions in this website (or the MSDN website) solved it. Everytime I create a new Windows Phone 8.1 project I get the `XamlParseException`, even when I choose the Blank App project. I will list everything I tried.

- Reinstall VS 2015
- Reinstall VS 2015 without the SDK and then download it later with the emulators
- Enable Developer Mode on Windows
- Disable Project Code
- Open the .xaml files with the Automatic Editor Selector and XAML Designer
- Enable XAML Designer in the Options, **of course**
- Update Windows 10 (note: I couldn't upgrade to 1809, I'm stuck with 1803)
- Enable Hypervisor on the BIOS
- Reboot computer
- Adding the 'ThemeResources.xaml' manually on the project
- Build, Rebuild and Clean the solution
- Using different .NET Framework versions

Here is my App.xaml code:

```
<Application
x:Class="App2.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2">
```

Here is my MainPage.xaml code:

```
<Page
x:Class="App2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I can't get StackOverflow to show the last line of code, but I can assure you each and every tag is closed

Comment: try to setup Windows 8.1 in a VM and setup VS2015 there. Phone 8.1 is dead for some time, so MS no longer cares about anything related to it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I got it to work, I just needed to update to Windows 10 1089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work just by updating to Windows 10 1089, don't forget to enable Developer Mode once you upgrade, since "Sideload Apps" isn't enough.